# Can Azure Data Factory ingest an XML file stored in Azure Data Lake Store?

Tags: xml, azure, dataset, azure-data-lake

Is there some way to ingest XML files from the Azure Data Lake Store Gen1?  I'm attempting to create a DataSet in Azure Data Factory using Azure Data Lake Store Gen1.  However, XML doesn't appear to be a supported file format - only delimited files, etc.

I have imported an XML file into a folder structure inside of the Azure Data Lake Store.  I am now trying to create a DataSet inside of Azure Data Factory.  I have to choose Azure Data Lake Store Gen1 to select my file in the folder structure which it does just fine.  However, there is no XML format option  – only delimted and other file formats that are NOT XML!

What is the work-around for this?  I have to believe there is some way to ingest XML files from the Azure Data Lake Store, correct??

Comment: if you just want to copy the files as it, that's possible when you select "binary copy"

Answer (score 1):

The workaround solution is to create a custom activity, please refer to the offical document [`Use custom activities in an Azure Data Factory pipeline`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/transform-data-using-dotnet-custom-activity), its purpose as below.

> To move data to/from a data store that Data Factory does not support, or to transform/process data in a way that isn't supported by Data Factory, you can create a Custom activity with your own data movement or transformation logic and use the activity in a pipeline. The custom activity runs your customized code logic on an Azure Batch pool of virtual machines.